# Overload operators for std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, std, functor

Suppose you would like to perform mathematical operations on functions. Mathematically we know that `f(x)*g(x)` is also a function if `f` and `g` are.

How would one go about expressing that with `std::function`? I was thinking of overloading the mathematical operators something so:

```
typedef std::function<double(double)> func;

func operator * (const func &f, func &g) 
{
        auto temp = [&] () { return f( ?? ) * g ( ?? ); };
        return temp; 
}
```

But I'm not sure how the arguments of `f` and `g` would come into play here. Could I use `std::placeholders` for this? What would be the correct way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be

```
func operator* (const func &f, const func &g) 
{
        return [=](double x) { return f(x) * g(x); }
}
```

I don't recommend doing it, though. For one, because you can't add things to `std`, this operator can't be found by ADL, so you have to rely on plain unqualified lookup, which is brittle at best. Also, multiple layers of `std::function` is quite inefficient.

Comment: Thanks! Should have thought of that :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for type erasure in the return type. You'd really want something like this:

```
class composed {
   std::function<double(double)> f;
   std::function<double(double)> g;
public:
   composed(std::function<double(double)> f, std::function<double(double)> g) : f(f), g(g) { }
   double operator()(double x) { return f(x) * g(x); }
};
inline composed operator*(std::function<double(double)> f, std::function<double(double)> g) { return composed(f,g); }
```

This is more efficient than return a `std::function<double(double)>`. `composed` can still be convertedto one, if the caller wants to. But when you just pass it to `std::transform`, calling `composed` directly is more efficient.

In fact, an industrial-strength implementation of `operator*` would try to capture the actual types of `f` and `g` as well, so `composed` would become a template.